# (TensorFlow on Windows) ImportError: cannot import name 'model_analyzer'

Tags: python, virtualenv, tensorflow

I am attempting to train a TensorFlow model in Windows 10 using these steps: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr#requirements

I have installed virtualenv for Windows ([following this example](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/))

The source command is not recognized by Windows. Are the additional steps to the virtualenv command required for Windows, or is there an alternative usage of the source command?

Note that the subsequent pip install commands worked (pip, tensorflow_gpu), but when I attempt to train using train.py  I get the following error:

```
 File "train.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tfprof import model_analyzer
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_analyzer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your virtualenv is configured correctly, but the code you are trying to use imports `tf.contrib.tfprof`, which is [not currently (as of TensorFlow 1.2) supported on Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11046).

However, since `tf.contrib.tfprof` is only used to provide profiling information, you should be able to run the code by manually removing the following line from `train.py`:

- [Line 27](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/56765e5b60f998a8e7023c3f088e657c0d25d1a4/attention_ocr/python/train.py#L27): `from tensorflow.contrib.tfprof import model_analyzer`

...and passing the flag `--show_graph_stats=false` when running the script.

Comment: Yes, that got me past that error. Thank you. I now keep having to add modules from the 'datasets' directory' down to the the python directory (fsns.py, fsns_test.py, unittest...etc). Feels like the paths are not correct somehow (I am new to python). I kept adding those and now stuck on this from train.py: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StringIO'.  Feels like I have not set all this up correctly.

Comment: Marked as answer, as this may deserve a new question. Thanks.

Comment: new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788042/tensorflow-on-windows-setting-up-virtualenv-and-path-set-by-source-command