# (Tensorflow on Windows) setting up virtualenv and path set by source command

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

I am attempting to train a TensorFlow model in Windows 10 using these steps: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr#requirements

I have installed virtualenv for Windows ([following this example](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/))

The source command is not recognized by Windows, what needs to be done so that when I run the [subsequent steps](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr#how-to-use-this-code) so that python sees what virtulenv created? Is there something related to the 'source' command needed in Windows? I can see virtualenv created the ~/.tensorflow folder, but I do not see a 'bin/activate' folder inside that. I tried adding the full path to ~/.tensorflow to my Windows PATH, but I still get the following error when I run the train on inception_v3.ckpt:

```
    import StringIO
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'
```

Comment: Note, the error above is after having coppied fsns.py and other files from the datasets folder down to the Python folder, this seems a mistake as I should instead be looking at why python does not see them when following the steps from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running TensorFlow on Windows, I would guess that you are using Python 3.x. The `StringIO` module was [removed in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), so the code you are running appears not to be compatible with Python 3.x. I would recommend filing an [issue on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues), but you may be able to fix it by replacing `import StringIO` with `import six`, and any uses of `StringIO.StringIO` with `six.StringIO`.

Comment: still have not ironed this all out yet, but see what you mean about this model targeting a previous version of python :/ ... for now, battling other issues when trying to setup that version of python with virtualenv. Right now looks like the windows build (1.2.1) for tensorflow_gpu is broken, or pypi.pythong.org is having other issues.